# Insect Identification (badly damaged corpse)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: A dead insect against the netting of a strainer. The insect has a dark body, a reddish head, and yellow at the other end.]

The photo is of the insect in question in a strainer. The body of the insect is just over half an inch long. I see a separated wing cover and leg in the photo as well.

My location is New Hampshire, USA. Given that it is February (middle of winter), I don't think it was sourced locally.

I believe that this came from a packaged item that would have been sealed in San Diego, CA or possibly in Asheville, NC. The packaging likely occurred no earlier than June or July of last year. The packaging would have occurred indoors in a manufacturing-type setting.

After coming out of the packaging, this individual was submerged in liquid on a stir plate for 36 hours, so it took quite a beating.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It might be helpful if you [edit]ed your post to include what kind of product the insect was packaged with. ——— You may also want to the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 